# transfer to contract fails

Tags: solidity

I want to use the `transfer` function to send value to another contract from a contract, however it fails if I set a state variable in the called contract as seen below:

```
contract Sender {
    function() payable {
    }

    function sendTo(address receiverAddr) {
        var receiver = Receiver(receiverAddr);
        receiver.transfer(this.balance); // This fails
    }
}

contract Receiver {
    bool public received;

    function() payable {
        received = true; 
    }
}
```

Doing other stuff doesn't cause an error. What is the problem with setting a state variable in the fallback function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when the fallback function is called by doing receiver.transfer() it will not have the necessary gas to modify the state variable.

According to Solidity docs:

> In such a context, there is usually very little gas available to the
>   function call (to be precise, 2300 gas), so it is important to make
>   fallback functions as cheap as possible. Note that the gas required by
>   a transaction (as opposed to an internal call) that invokes the
>   fallback function is much higher, because each transaction charges an
>   additional amount of 21000 gas or more for things like signature
>   checking.
>
> In particular, the following operations will consume more gas than the
>   stipend provided to a fallback function:
>
> ```
> Writing to storage
> Creating a contract
> Calling an external function which consumes a large amount of gas
> Sending Ether
> ```

If you wanted to have your Sender contract to transfer ether to the Receiver contract, instead of calling receiver.transfer you should implement a function in Receiver that receives ether, like so:

```
contract Sender {

    function() payable{

    }

    function sendTo(address receiverAddr) payable {
        var receiver = Receiver(receiverAddr);
        receiver.payMe.value(msg.value)();
    }
}

contract Receiver {
    bool public received;

    function() payable{

    }

    function payMe() payable returns(bool success) {
        received = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example the function `payMe` returns `bool`, right ? What is the purpose of a transaction to return bool. I thought that transactions would ignore returns since they are async by nature.

Comment: Actually, other Solidity functions can read a return value even if it's a transaction. 
In my example above you could do if(receiver.payMe.value(msg.value)()) to do something depending if the payMe function returned true or false.